# Prevent dimming screen in iOS App Extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-app-extension, uiapplication

I'm developing an iOs app with an Action App Extension. While the Action App Extension is running, I want to prevent the device from dimming its screen.

I've added `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES]` but its giving me this error.

> 'sharedApplication' is unavailable: not available on iOS (App Extension) - Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead.

So I want to ask, what are the `"view controller based solutions"` ? What Is the alternate for `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES]` in iOS App Extension ?

Comment: was it added on the app delegate?

Comment: no, I added it to my App Extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extensions cannot modify the host app, by design.  If the host app doesn't care about screen dimming, there's nothing you can do.